# How to link to a parametrized urlpattern?

Tags: django

I have a parametrized urlpattern
`path("editpage/<str:title>", views.editpage, name="editpage")`
How would i go about and provide a link to this in the html?
`<a href="/editpage/{{ title }}">{{ title }}</a>`
I dont want something like this, where the link is "hardcoded". Rather i want to use the feature
'{% url 'editpage' %}'. But this yields: Reverse for 'editpage' with no arguments not found. But how do i pass in the extra information?

I tried

```
{% url 'editpage' title='{{ title }}' %}
```

but that doesnt work
Edit: ok i tried your suggestion, but cant resolve the still lingering error
urls.py:

```
path("wiki/<str:title>", views.article, name="article")
```

views.py:

```py
def index(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
    })
def article(request, title):
if title not in util.list_entries():
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html")
else:
    content = markdown2.markdown(util.get_entry(title))
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/article.html", {
        "title": title,
        "content": content
    })
```

index.html:

```html
<ul>
{% for entry in entries %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'article' title=entry  %}">{{ entry }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables in a template tag are referenced by the identifier, not between double curly brackets (`{{ … }}`), so:

```
<a href="{% url 'editpage' title=title %}">link</a>
```

You thus were quite close.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I still have an error in my code apparently: NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'article' with keyword arguments '{'title': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['wiki/(?P<title>[^/]+)\\Z']. Do you have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @katle: that is because either the `title` variable does not exist in your template, or is empty, a `<str:..>` does not accept an empty string.